# Give permissions to www-data user to run a local script

Tags: linux, bash, php

I actually try to launch a gnome-terminal with a PHP script, and seems I have some problems with the users `www-data`;

My script only makes an `ls -l` command in a directory (is just for a test) and I run it with a php page on my local website.

Here is the gnome-terminal command in my bash script (it runs perfectly when I double-click):

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/opt/cuckoo -x bash -c "ls -l"
```

and here is the call on the php-page:

```
system("/my/path/to/the/script/script.sh");
```

I have some "echo" in my script and I see it in the PHP page after I try to run the script with the website.

I think `www-data` doesn't have the permissions so I try to give the user ownership of the script with the `chown` command with no result, and at last I tried the `sudo visudo` command and gave `www-data` root permissions for this script only (with `NO PASSWD` arg).

It didn't work. I tried to change the php command, replacing `system` by `exec`, and show the result with `$output` but it's the same as well.

Can PHP really run a terminal or did I maybe fool myself?

Comment: *i already ask my question with php tag* — where?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't think you need gnome-terminal at all.

Comment: Won't gnome-terminal need an xserver?

Comment: Why not just use `exec` for all of the commands you want to run?  It seems like overkill to spawn a terminal just to run commands when you can run them directly from PHP.

Comment: slhck : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653921/cant-open-gnome-terminal-with-php


Keith: yes it's my fault but ls is just for a example, i want to run a python script who need 2 gnome terminal open, my script do that very well so i just want to run it with php interface.


Paul: i can run the script well, you think i need xserver if i want to run it with php ?


Breakthrough : i try with exec too and shell_exec, but it doesn't made any results. i think is the problems come from the permissions

Comment: @zoomb No, I meant that the idea of running a python script inside a gnome-terminal running in an xserver called from a php script via a web-server is um, perhaps not the best approach.  Why does your python script need a gnome terminal?  Please [edit] your question and provide a load more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you have to take into account

1. If you want to `ls` a directory, "who" run that command could *traverse* that folder (so, +x permission is absolutely necessary)
2. Is your php script running under a server? If it does, maybe you have to change the owner in agreement with this
3. Dependent on the second point: please keep attention when you **chown** on files

Comment: The php script is on the folder var/www/. It,s a local server, but i already add my local user to the www-data group and try after with visudo to give full permissions to the user www-data for the script, and give the ownership too with chown, maybe i have forget something ?

Comment: @zoomb Under what user runs your page?

Comment: under the www-data user, int the /var/www/mysite/path i give him full permissions for the script and add the local user in the www-data group

Comment: I suppose that he would run in "normal" condition. Maybe gnome-terminal are just different respect other kind of terminal

Comment: yes i think too, i try with another command than gnome-term so